# How to pick the value wrt latest timestamp from dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyspark

I have a dataframe as shown below.

```
vehicle status  created date and time
A2345   OK      2022-12-05T04:24:06.000
A2345   NOT_OK  2022-12-05T04:25:06.000
B234    NOT_OK  2022-12-05T07:25:06.000
B234    NOT_OK  2022-12-05T06:25:06.000
```

for distinct "vehicle" for "created date and time"  if "status" is NOT_OK then print "yes"
else "no"

output should be like:
yes
yes

how to achieve this using pyspark dataframe

Comment: Your expected output and dataset do not match. There are four distinct timestamps with three as status `NOT_OK`; but your output has only two `YES`. You should provide output against each row to make it clear.

Comment: its for distinct vehicle

Comment: You should provide samples for `NO` as well. Please provide comprehensive sample else the solution provided will work on sample data; but may not work on your actual data.